# How to check remote server time via psexec

Tags: psexec

I tried command like below. But can't see server time.

```
psexec \\SERVER_NAME -i -u USERNAME -p PWD "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c time /t"
```

Or is there any alternative? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
net time \\SERVER_NAME
```

Ps. This question really belongs at ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

I have about 100 servers in my company. Once i had to check system time on all servers.
The solution was:

```
psexec -d -i cmd /c nettime.bat
```

content of nettime.bat file :

```
@echo off
net time \\server01 >>c:\1.txt
net time \\server02 >>c:\1.txt
net time \\server03 >>c:\1.txt
```